# trailing / breaks css, ie localhost/login vs localhost/login/

Tags: express, routes, ejs

I am working on building an express server that displays views from ejs. my browser will sometimes autofill the rest of a url for me and will put in localhost:port/login/, which means the page is no longer able to find the css anymore. If I manually type it out to not have the trailing / at the end then the page loads and looks fine. Is this a common problem when working with express and ejs? Is there a way to route all paths that end with a slash to their non-slash counterpart?

Comment: Why can't it find the CSS?

Comment: it looks like it's changing the path. So when navigating to /login it loads the page and web inspector shows the sources are all in the same folder as each other. But when going to /login/ it shows a folder called login and then a / file (that has all of the same ejs content as expected) but now the css is one directory up. Is there a way to find the css from a global path?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed this by adding a `/` in front of all of the paths for my stylesheets and scripts. So, instead of `<link rel="stylesheet"  href="css/style">`, I am using `<link rel="stylesheet"  href="/css/style">`.

Now, whether I use `localhost/login` or `localhost/login/`, it still finds that CSS source either way.

Comment: This is the correct approach (unless you have file-relative CSS, obviously).